# Why is ng-model not being set to undefined when changing programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, validation

Example plunker in question:
http://plnkr.co/edit/GgqA2gHYch1REj9BoHW3?p=preview

According to [the documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue):

> If we want to change the control's DOM value programmatically, we should update the ngModel scope expression. Its new value will be picked up by the model controller, which will run it through the $formatters, $render it to update the DOM, and finally call $validate on it.

So in the plunker I update the scope expression to a new value via 'setNameToSomethingInvalid'.  Its associated ngModelController is clearly set to invalid and so I expect the following [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validate) to apply:

> If the validity changes to invalid, the model will be set to undefined

Instead, the model value is set to the invalid string.  What am I doing wrong?

Mandatory plunker code:

```
// controller definition
var vm = this;
var initialName = "a valid name";
vm.user = {
  name: initialName
};

vm.setNameToSomethingInvalid = function setNameToSomethingInvalid() {
  vm.user.name = "not-a-valid-name";
};

vm.resetName = function resetName() {
  vm.user.name = initialName;
};

// html input declaration
<input id="name"
  name="name"
  type="text"
  ng-pattern="/^[a-z ]+$/"
  ng-model="vm.user.name">
```

Comment: Angular doc says :      **$modelValue
* 
The value in the model that the control is bound to.**

Comment: I did see that, seems to be inconsistent.  However if modelValue is always the resolved ng-model expression, then how is this the angular-advised way to update the dom programmatically?  We are left with invalid state which is not good!